# Convert Unix epoch time to datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I have been searching for a long time to find a solution to my problem.

I get the data from the column I want using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Live_data_test.xlsx","Sheet1")

number_of_entries = len(df.loc[:, 'Time'])
number_of_entries_last_3 = number_of_entries - 3
unix_x1 = df.loc[number_of_entries_last_:number_of_entries, 'Time']
print(unix_x1)
```

I get the output

```
10    1.513753e+09
11    1.513753e+09
12    1.513753e+09
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

I want to convert this time into readable time so I can input it into the x axis of a matplotlib graph.

```
real_x1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(unix_x1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: time data '10    1.513753e+09\n11    1.513753e+09\n12    1.513753e+09\nName: Time, dtype: float64' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

how do I get this unix time to output into a readable format for a user?

I am a little new to code so if you answer, could you please explain the reasoning if you can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has to do with converting the values that you've read (looks like seconds after Unix epoch, i.e. January 1, 1970) into [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects. The error you are getting is because your times are just a floating-point number, but that is not how you are trying to handle them.

Assuming these are seconds after Unix epoch, you need to create your datetimes using a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) from a start point defined as the Unix epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime(1970, 1, 1)  # Unix epoch start time
df['datetime'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: start + timedelta(seconds=x))
```

The last line creates a new column in your dataframe called `'datetime'` and populates it by reading the `'Time'` column in as `x`, and calculating the time `x` seconds after Unix epoch.

Note: if you want to convert these `datetime` objects into the time string that you specified, we can do this by creating a new column with [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
df['string_time'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 38):

Pandas can read unix epoch time, use unit parameter

```
pd.to_datetime('1.513753e+09', unit = 's')

Timestamp('2017-12-20 06:56:40')
```

You can pass your column using

```
pd.to_datetime(df[<your_datetime_column>], unit = 's')
```

Comment: Seriously underrated answer. Should have the green check

Answer (score 0):

you could try 
`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y%m%d.0')`

Comment: Mind enhancing your answer, adding the reasons why to do that, and perhaps some documentation for a better quality answer