# pd.read_sql formatting issue with timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the below to extract data from database using cx_Oracle.connect for connection. I am having issue when the field I'm trying to extract from database is of datatype TIMESTAMP(6).

Value retrieved is 1625236451324000000 instead of 02-JUL-21 02.54.05.569000 PM

```
df_ora = pd.read_sql(sql_query_lpi, con=md_connection)
df_list=df_ora.values.tolist()
for columnname in df_list:
    run_info = dict()
    run_info['UPDATE_TS'] = columnname[0]
```

Any special formatting required in pandas to handle this ?

Thank you for any help/suggestion.

Comment: The integer value appears to be an epoch time.  [Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49949780/6340496).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass in the `unit` argument when casting it to a datetime,

`pd.to_datetime(your_col, unit='ns')`

```
In [4]: pd.Timestamp(1625236451324000000, unit='ns')
Out[4]: Timestamp('2021-07-02 14:34:11.324000')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1625236451324000000]})
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], unit='ns')
```

---

```
print(df)
                   col                date_col
0  1625236451324000000 2021-07-02 14:34:11.324
```

#### Edit.

If you need to preserve a format then use `.dt.srftime`, note this will turn your timestamp into a string.

```
 df['date_col_sql'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], unit='ns')\
                        .dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f')


                   col                date_col               date_col_sql
0  1625236451324000000 2021-07-02 14:34:11.324  02-Jul-21 02.34.11.324000
```

Comment: Thank you Umar . I would like to preserve the format of timestamp format i.e., 02-JUL-21 02.54.05.569000 PM in the above example so I can use that in query again.  Is there a way to do this ? Thank you.

Comment: @pats4u see edit, sorry I've not been on until right now, hope this helps.